# Jquery - datepicker dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to set datepicker default values for to and from fields with todays date for to field and a week back to to field, like this:

```
  //datepicker
  var date = new Date();
  var date = date.toDateString();
  var weekBack = new Date();
  var weekBack = new Date(weekBack.setDate(weekBack.getDate() - 7));
  var weekBack = weekBack.toDateString();
  console.log(date);
  $('#datePicker').fdatepicker({
        closeButton: false,
    initialDate: weekBack,
        format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    timelines();
    barCharts();
  });

  $('#datePicker1').fdatepicker({
        closeButton: false,
    initialDate: date,
        format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    timelines();
    barCharts();
  });
```

But I then my both fields have the todays date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var date = date.toDateString();
```

returns String, so String doesn't contain the `getDate()` method.

Just don't use it `var date = date.toDateString();`.

```
var date = new Date();
var weekBack = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7));
// weekBack is Fri May 13 2016 17:36:12 GMT+0300 (Russia TZ 2 Standard Time) for me
```

If you want to get `weekBack` as a timestamp don't wrap it with `new Date`:

```
var date = new Date();
var weekBack = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);
// weekBack is 1463150337387
```

[UPD]
The example are here - https://jsfiddle.net/ht4eg4zs/

Comment: I have some changes the way you suggested, but I am getting the same dates now for both fields

Comment: Thanks that is it!